# Can I get Social Forward to direct to a specific link?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, socialpost

We are using the Social Forward feature to attempt to direct a post to Facebook for a client. The desired user experience would be that the subscriber clicks a Facebook share icon from the email, and is brought to a page where the post is already set for the user - we have selected a title, description, and image to pre-populate. All of this is working as expected, but the post directs to a page that appears to have been created by the Marketing Cloud, titled "pages.domainname.com".

Is there any way to modify this webpage to direct to the client's website as opposed to this predetermined page?

Answer (score 1):

Not with the built-in Social Forward, no.  However, you can use AMPScript to build a link using Facebook sharer.php within the email.  NOTE: This URL based sharing has been deprecated by Facebook, so use this at your own risk.  It doesn't work on mobile devices.

Here's an example:

```
%%[
var @fbTitle, @fbImage, @fbSummary, @fbURL, @fbPostURL
set @fbTitle = "this is the title"
set @fbImage = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
set @fbSummary = "whee whoa whoops"
set @fbURL = "http://sprignaturemoves.com/"

set @fbPostURL = concat("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p%5Btitle%5D=", urlencode(@fbTitle,1),"&amp;p%5Burl%5D=",urlencode(@fbURL,1),"&amp;p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=",urlencode(@fbImage,1),"&amp;p%5Bsummary%5D=",urlencode(@fbSummary,1))
]%%

<a href="%%=redirectto(@fbPostUrl)=%%">Post to Facebook</a>
```

I have some other social sharing examples on my blog [here](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-social-links/).

Comment: Adam, I am not able to get this working - when I use the exact code above, it pulls title, etc from your website and not the variables you listed out above. I added in the image, title, summary, etc. and all it's pulling in is the link.

Comment: It looks like in some preliminary research, this feature is no longer allowed by Facebook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956229/has-facebook-sharer-php-changed-to-no-longer-accept-detailed-parameters

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately,  there's not a good email alternative -- at least that I've found.  The ET way for sharing the from a landing page leaves a lot to be desired.  The whole point of social sharing is to link directly to what you're wanting to share, not the email version of it.  I feel your pain.   Technically you could create a landing page that accepts parameters and implements the full [Facebook Javascript API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2) method of sharing.  Then you could just link to your landing page in your email and include the URL parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, Adam - Greatly appreciated.